# Unit testing a class with constructor as the only public method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a class which is as below:

```
class ToTest {
    private MemberOne memberOne;
    private MemberTwo memberTwo;

    public ToTest(ParamOne paramOne, ParamTwo paramTwo) {
        setMemberOne(paramOne);
        setMemberTwo(paramTwo);
    }

    private setMemberOne(ParamOne paramOne) {
        //Build the object.
    }

    private setMemberTwo(ParamTwo paramTwo) {
        //build another object.
    }
}
```

The reason setters are only accessible via constructor is that I do not want to change a object once initialized because there is a dependency between `memberOne` and `memberTwo`(an example could be `MemberOne` represents table header and `MemberTwo` represent data in table and to keep coding simple and free from constraints checking if the number of columns are equal in header and data set).

As a practice I do not write test cases for private methods. What would be a good strategy for writing test cases for this class.

Comment: What does the object even do then?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: There are get methods to get these objects and then it is passed to a JSP where the information is extracted by tags written to handle `MemberOne` and `MemberTwo`.

Comment: If you have no public-facing functions, no side-effects, and don't want to use reflection, there's nothing to test in the first place.

Comment: @DaveNewton I thought that using reflection might be the only alternative I have but just wanted to see if there is anything else that comes up.

Comment: So the getters are your public interface, so you would write your tests against the public getters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the building of `MemberOne` and `MemberTwo` to a separate class.

```
private setMemberOne(ParamOne paramOne) {
    memberOne = new MemberOneBuilder().buildFromParam(paramOne);
}
```

with

```
public class MemberOneBuilder {
    public MemberOne buildFromParam(ParamOne paramOne) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Now you can easily test the building process separately.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting this, however couldn't you make memberOne and memberTwo final, and then make setMemberOne and setMemberTwo public? Then you could instantiate memberOne and memberTwo, but they would not be able to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more of a hypothetical scenario, whereas just for the sake of doing it, if we got to write such a code and also the test-case for it, using Reflection in the Unit-Test class is the only way out here.